# Error shown while trying to execute c# program

Tags: c#, rdlc

I am trying to create a rdlc report but hit error while I trying to execute the program

> Error: ""=Items collection cannot be modified when the DataSource
>   property is set."

```
Private void btnGenerate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
       string connectionstring = "MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Data Source=ECSTSRD;Initial Catalog=SSWSQL;User ID=sswuser;Password=sswuser123";
       SqlConnection myconnection = new SqlConnection(connectionstring);

   myconnection.Open();

   string sql = "SELECT customer, imp_license_no, psq_level FROM customer WHERE customer= @cust1";

   SqlCommand custcom = new SqlCommand(sql, myconnection);

   custcom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cust1", cboFrom.SelectedValue.ToString());

   SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(custcom);
   DataSet1 ds = new DataSet1();
   da.Fill(ds, "whbal");

   cboFrom.DataBindings.Clear();
   cboTo.DataBindings.Clear();

   cboFrom.Items.Add(ds.Tables["whbal"]);

   cboFrom.DataSource = ds.Tables["whbal"];
   cboFrom.DisplayMember = "customer";
   cboFrom.ValueMember = "customer";

   myconnection.Close();

   reportViewer1.Reset();
   reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();

   LocalReport report = new LocalReport();


   reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("DataSet1", customerBindingSource));
   report.ReportPath = "Report1.rdlc";
   reportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh();

}
```

Can anyone please comment and help if anything I missed?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `cboFrom.Items.Add()` call is completely wrong.
When using databinding, you can't manipulate `Items` at all.

Comment: so how should I modify it?
I have found a lot of website which guide to do the rdlc report..
But I cannot get through why some use data set, and why some use data table..confusing..

Comment: Just remove that line.  You probably also shouldn't clear the databindings.

Comment: Ok now the error is solved..thanks so much and appreciated..
BUt..can I ask another question? 

after i click on the button,  the report is not shown and the combo box items is dissapear.
Do u know what's is the error? My coding for report above is correct?